# "The association has been severed but the relationship is either marked as 'Required' or is implicitly required..."

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am getting the following error when trying to add a migration:

```
PS C:\Code\morpher.ru\Morpher.Database> dotnet ef migrations add AddQazaqFeatures --startup-project=../Morpher.Database.Design
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.InvalidOperationException: The association between entity types 'Service' and 'Deployment' has been severed but the relationship is either m
arked as 'Required' or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a requi
red relationship is severed, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.  Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLoggin
g' to see the key values.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.HandleConceptualNulls(Boolean sensitiveLoggingEnabled, Boolean forc
e, Boolean isCascadeDelete)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.CascadeDelete(InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean force, IEnumerable`1 fore
ignKeys)
 ...
```

My code:

```cs
    public class Deployment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public short? Port { get; set; }
        public string BasePath { get; set; }
    }

    public class Service
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
        
        public virtual ICollection<Endpoint> Endpoints { get; set; }
        
        public virtual ICollection<Deployment> Deployments { get; set; }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Service>().HasData(new Service
        {
            Name = "Веб-сервис «Морфер»",
            UrlSlug = "ws",
            Id = 1
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Deployment>().HasData(new Deployment
        {
            Host = "ws3.morpher.ru",
            ServiceId = 1,
            Id = 1
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Deployment>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Host).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
            entity.Property(e => e.BasePath).HasMaxLength(512);

            entity.HasOne(deployment => deployment.Service)
                .WithMany(service => service.Deployments)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ServiceId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Deployments_Services");
        });
     }
```

There are numerous StackOverflow questions mentioning the same error ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66597610/1291717), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59934765/1291717), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46040886/1291717)), but they are mostly to do with removing entities while not having a CASCADE delete policy or a nullable foreign key.

In my case, I am trying to add new rows and I don't see why it is considering the relationship 'severed'. Is setting ServiceId = 1 not enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue in latest at this time EF Core 3.1 version (3.1.28) by first removing the model data seeding code (`HasData` calls), then adding migration for just creating the tables/relationships, then adding the data seeding code and attempting to add new migration.

It does not happen in latest EF Core 6.0, so apparently you are hitting EF Core 3.1 defect/bug which has been fixed somewhere down on the road. So you either need to upgrade to a newer EF Core version (with all associated burdens like retesting everything, breaking changes etc.), or use the workaround below.

The workaround is to replace the [`DeleteBehavior.Restrict`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DeleteBehavior.ClientNoAction)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-6.0) with either `ClientNoAction` or `NoAction`. Values of that enum and documentation of what they do is kind of messy, but all these 3 values seem to generate one and the same regular enforced FK constraint (with no cascade) in the database, and differ only by client side behavior, or in other words, what does EF Core change tracker do with related *tracked* entities when "deleting" a principal entity. And in this particular case, `Restrict" throws exception when there are tracked (loaded) related entity instances, while the other two won't.

I know you think you are just "adding data", but EF Core model data seeding is more than that - it tries to keep that data, so in some circumstances it needs to update or delete previously added data. Which in general works, except when there are bugs in the EF Core codebase, like in this case.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reproduce the issue. You are right, it's not the first migration in this db model, and the goal of this migration was to 'just add more seed data'. I've already done a workaround by just inserting the data at app startup, so I'll try your suggesting the next time I need to add more seed data. Thanks for your answer.